# Do I need to reformat? Win 8 > Dual Boot > Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I currently am running Windows 8, and want to set up a dual boot with Ubuntu, but I don't want to have to reformat and lose all my Windows files and settings. How do I go about setting up my first dual boot without risking loss of information?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reformat anything.

Simply boot an Ubuntu installation image. The install wizard will guide you to create a dual-boot ('Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1') and you won't loose any data.

Comment: That's it? That seems easy. So if I have a x64 system I should use a x64 image, but otherwise there's nothing to be aware of?

Comment: Indeed, use the x64 image. As @MadMike pointed out, give a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), you will find all the important informations to make sure you won't mess anything :)